# Magento 2.0 Get POST data inside Productsaveafter Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.0

I have a quick question, how can we get the POST data inside the execute method of Productsaveafter class?  I added new input fields in the Product form page in admin and would like to save them onto a new table.

```
class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest(); 
        $productData = $product->getData('params');
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($product); exit;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could try:  `$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. i also tested $observer->getRequest()->getPostValue();  also error. although when I do a print_r($observer) I can see the post data.

Comment: this is the one I see, i just don;'t have any idea how to extract it:  
[postParams:protected] => Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
 [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
  (
   [form_key] => tiQ1H13YxgAHBLPi
   [product] => Array
    (
     [name] => testAfterSave
     [sku] => testAfterSave
     [price] => 1,200.00

Comment: maybe you could use the toArray() function and then get it from the array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your observer constructor do:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then in your code use `$this->_request` to fetch post params.

Comment: i tried this and this is indeed what i am looking for.  Thanks Petar.

Comment: That's brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from $oberver, example bellow :

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
   'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after',
   ['controller' => $this, 'product' => $product]
);
```

In this example product is pass to event, so in your observer, you can get this variable :

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getData('product');
    $sku = $product->getSku();
}
```

Hope this help someone :)
Will